# Gltf file exported via GLTFExporter is grey color

Tags: three.js, blender

I exported a glft file on [this demo page](https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_exporter_gltf).
And then, I imported the file to Blender but 3d model looks grey color and seems missing color.

How to solve this problem?
Or doesn't glft have color data?

I'm new to glft and Blender, I'd appreciate if you share any solutions or references what I should read to solve it.

Comment: How did you import the glTF file in Blender? Maybe there is a problem with the importer? What happens if you view your exported model on this site: https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/ ? Same result?

Comment: Importing on the site works. It has color as expected. I use gltf-blender-importer add-on: https://github.com/ksons/gltf-blender-importer.

Comment: So maybe there is a problem with the importer. I suggest you file a bug at the respective github issue section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When debugging something like this, the first step is to narrow down the source of the issue. If the model appears correctly on viewers like http://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ or https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/, then the exporter is probably doing its part correctly. If not, file a bug on the threejs repo about the exporter.

If the Blender importer you're using can't load the file, I'd suggest filing a bug on that repository instead. I'd also suggest trying https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO, if you haven't already.

Finally, note that by default when Blender opens, textures are *disabled* in the viewport. You have to enable *Texture*, *Material*, or *Rendered* in the *Viewport Shading* menu:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Don McCurdy. I found the cause of the problem is disabling textures as you said!